# jquery .val() not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, return-value

In the below function I want to show and hide an element based on other options selected on the page (radio buttons). The problem is, the `var complianceMember` always returns the first value for the set of radio buttons it's part of and not the selected value, why is this? The other two variables return the correct values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="waste-management-plan"]').change(function () {

        var producerType = $('input[name="producertype"]').val();
        var complianceMember = $('input[name="compliance-member"]').val();

        if ($(this).val() == 'Y' && complianceMember == 'Y' && producerType == 'both' ) {
            $('.producerOp3').show();
        } else {
            $('.producerOp3').hide();
            console.log( $(this).val(),complianceMember,producerType );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a filter to find the checked radio button and then get its value. You can use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
var complianceMember = $('input[name="compliance-member"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Out of interest, why one group returning the correct value while the other is not? The one returning the correct value has two options while the var returning the wrong value has 3 options. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond whether `producertype` also is an radio group?

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond if so then you will have to use the `checked` filter there also... otherwise it should fail

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned radio group, you have to get the value of radio button which is checked

```
var complianceMember = $('input[name="compliance-member"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Someone got there a little before you.

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond Sometime happens :) for your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348052/jquery-val-not-returning-correct-value#comment30373411_20348088), I guess for `producertype` you might have clicked the `first radio button` and therefore you got it right. `$('input[name="producertype"]').val();` try selecting both options it will **always gives the value of first radio button.**